# How to move lots of data from AWS Oracle RDS instance to S3?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a huge amount of data in one table (~7 billion rows) in an AWS Oracle RDS instance.  The end result is I want that table as pipe-separated values stored in S3 so that I can read it into EMR.  This is basically a one-time thing so I need it to work accurately and without having to re-run the whole upload because something timed out; I don't really care how it works or how difficult/annoying it is to set up.  I have root access on the Oracle box.  I looked at Data Pipelines but it appears they only support MySQL and I must have it work with Oracle.  Also, I do not have enough hard drive space to dump the whole table to a CSV on the Oracle instance and then upload it.  How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sqoop (http://sqoop.apache.org/) to do this.  You can write a sqoop script that can be scheduled as an 'EMR Activity' under Data Pipeline.

Sqoop uses Hadoop and can open multiple connections to Oracle and load.

You can keep your raw data on S3 and directly read from that on EMR.  Or you can choose to copy that onto EMR using 'S3Distcp' activity (again scheduled on Data Pipeline, if you want).

If you dont have scheduling need, you can spin up an EMR cluster using EMR console - and run Sqoop on that.

Comment: This looks promising!  Thanks

Comment: It worked!  I ended up just using sqoop directly as a step on my EMR cluster and then using s3distcp as another step, so no data pipeline but I can see how it would be relatively easy to incorporate this into a data pipeline in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python/boto to do the same on a smaller scale.
To copy 7 billion records will take you "only" 8 days using single thread.
You can create 100 thread queue and process Oracle table partitions in parallel.
It may not be production solution it but it worked for my ad-hoc jobs.

Take a look at it [Oracle_To_S3_Data_Uploader](https://github.com/alexbuz/Oracle_To_S3_Data_Uploader/blob/master/README.md)